# Ctrl-Tab Shortcut Issue in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2013, ctrl

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013 and I am having issues with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut. It normally works perfectly for a bit when I first open a solution, but then stops. When it stops the dialog does not show up unless I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for a few seconds. When I do this the dialog flickers very quickly and then finally comes up. There have been times when it flickers, but never shows steadily.

I have checked to make sure it is not the keyboard and that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine in Chrome when it is not working in Visual Studio. If I restart Visual Studio I get the same experience where it works at first and then stops.

I am using Resharper 8.0.2, however I don't think that is affecting anything.

Comment: adaaaam, did you ever figure this out? I have had so many problems with VS2013. I am seeing exactly what you describe, including the flicker & being able to hold down to get it to come up. I have not had this on other machines though. It is happening on a Windows VM running from a Macbook. I didn't know if it was some kind of bad keyboard signals due to those factors.

Comment: I was not able to find a solution, but I don't have the issue any more. I am using VS2013 version 12.0.31101 and resharper 8.2.1. Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried to reset your setting by using devenv.exe /resetsetting flag ?
Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx

Comment: It flickers *because* you held down the key.  It is an environmental problem, you probably have a very slow or fragmented paging file.  VS2013 certainly works best with 8 GB of RAM and an SSD, that money is well-spent.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have **text-to-speech narrator** enabled?
To fix this, just uncheck all checkboxes under "Text-To-Speech" narrator software.

> --> To open Narrator using the keyboard, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>, press <kbd>R</kbd>, type narrator, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might solve your issue with the following info:

> Under certain conditions, the navigator window gets "stuck" and doesn't close when you release Ctrl - you'll need to manually close it
>   by making a selection or closing the navigator.  This behavior occurs
>   under the following conditions:
>
> 1) The registry value
>   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio[version]\General\NavigatorIsSticky
>   is set to 1  2) Sticky keys are enabled in Windows  3) The
>   SPI_GETSCREENREADER flag is set in Windows, which can be caused either
>   by an actual screen reader, or by certain tools like Inspect.exe or
>   AccEvent.exe from the Windows SDK
>
> For condition 1 or 2, simply deleting the registry key or disabling
>   sticky keys should solve the problem.  I experienced condition 3, most
>   likely from one of the mentioned tools failing to unset the flag
>   properly.

Though the source talks about different issue, it may point to the same outcome you've encountered. if method 1 and 2 don't solve your issue , go to the source below and implement the described code.

Source: http://tilt.carr.no/Post/12/visual-studio-ide-navigator-stuck

I hope it will address your issue...

**Update** if all fails , I point you to the following issue in SuperUser:
https://superuser.com/questions/816661/ctrltab-not-working-in-any-programs

Comment: Thanks - something in here solved it for me. I'm not sure what. I ran the code for changing SPI_GETSCREENREADER but it didn't seem to be set, so I tried to set it, but when I checked the flag again it was the same. But now I can ctrl+tab with the normal navigator (Window.NextDocumentWindowNav) and it does not flicker on and off. Baffled.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking to see if your anti-virus/mal-ware protection software is actively scanning `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`.

After upgrading to VS2013, we managed to considerably improve the IDE's responsiveness by adding an exclusion for this file.  In our case, AVG's malicious behaviour scanning caused even simple keyboard operations, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> between screens, to take an age.